# What post processing was used for this rosy, vintage, and soft photo?

Tags: post-processing, camera-settings, vintage

[image: A pink vintage look]

I've been looking this filter for a long time. It's rosy, vintage, and very soft.  If you can find suggest the saturation or the contrast that would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 4):

3 things stand out to me in this picture:

1. The color tint is pushed towards magenta. To imitate this, I would simply use your photo editing app's white balance tool and move the green/magenta slider towards magenta.
2. The color temperature is pushed towards yellow. To imitate this, move the white balance's blue/yellow slider towards yellow.
3. The blacks also seem to be a little washed out, like the black point was lowered significantly. You can imitate this with the Curves tool by taking the black point and moving it up. (I say lowered because I tend to prefer using the levels tool, and with levels you'd need to bring the black point down. With curves you move it up to achieve the same effect.)

For fun, I've undone the effect by doing the opposite of what I said above. Here's what it looks like with the settings I used:

[image: Undoing the filter]

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of color cast and elevated black level.

We can't know what is really white in this picture, but assuming the doorframe is white, the white reference is (1, .804, .943).  That explains the reddish-magenta cast.

The darkest point is (.050, .112, .250), which explains the apparent bluish wash in the dark areas.

To show this, here is the picture with the color balance set so that the doorframe near the top left of the picture is white, and the darkest part black.  I also non-linearly lightened the dark areas to make the picture look more "normal".  This removes some of the splotchiness in the dark areas.

[image]